# Массивы php и их обработка

Tags: php

Дан массив произвольного размера с числами в пределах от 1 до 1 000 000. В этом массиве все числа уникальные, кроме одного числа, которое повторяется два раза. Найти это число. Решить задачу с минимальным использованием процессорного времени.

Вот такая интересная задачка. Принимаются все идеи.

Пришло на ум вот такое решение:

```
    $result=array();
    $true=true;
    for($i=0;!$result[$v=$array[$i]]&&$i<ARRAY_ELEMENT_COUNT;$i++){
        $result[$v]=&$true; 
        unset($v);
    }
    $number=$array[$i];
```

Какие еще идеи можно применить?

Числа в массиве перемешаны:

```
    define('ARRAY_ELEMENT_COUNT',1000);
    $array=array();
    for($index=0;$index<ARRAY_ELEMENT_COUNT;$index++)
        $array[$index]=$index+1;

    shuffle($array);
    //Добавим повторяющийся елемент
    srand((float)microtime() * 1000000);// эта команда для чистоты эксперимента
    $pos=&rand(0,ARRAY_ELEMENT_COUNT-1);
    do{
        $val=rand(1,ARRAY_ELEMENT_COUNT-1);
    }while($array[$pos]==$val);
    $array[$pos]=$val;
    unset($val,$pos);
```

Comment: Я что-то не понял условия:

    !$result[$v=$array[$i]]

Все числа последовательно идут или как? Если числа перемешаны случайным образом, то это не верный код.

Еще не понятно - зачем проверять

    $i<ARRAY_ELEMENT_COUNT; //? 

В задании написано - в массиве 100% будет повторяющееся число, соответственно такая проверка ( я не о реальном коде, а строго с т.з. задачи ) - бессмысленна.

У вас на каждой итерации происходит проверка этого условия (что, в контексте этой задачи - абсолютно излишне).

Ну и $i++ медленнее ++$i :D

Comment: Согласен, но думаю задача с подвохом и отсутсвие проверок на ошибки сочтут за некомпетентность.
А условие !$result[$v=$array[$i]] примерно одно и тоже что isset($result[$v=$array[$i]]). За ++$i отдельное спасибо! Ну и числа перемешаны. Сейчас скину как я заполняю его для тестов.

Comment: так ЗАЧЕМ ЭТА ПРОВЕРКА НУЖНА?..

Как раз таки, ИМХО, задача несет **сугубо академический** характер, соответственно вас не в коем случае не сочтут не компетентным

Несколько уточнений - какова максимальная длина массива и возможно ли, например, что $arr[0] - число, $arr[1] - не существует, $arr[2] - опять число, $arr[3] - не существует...?

PS: так и не понял - поясните пожалуйста каким образом (даже теоретически) может помочь array_diff? Я просто не асилил

Comment: array_diff($исходный массив,$этот же массив но без повторяющихся элеентов=array_unique($исходный массив)) Думаю так?

Comment: $i<ARRAY_ELEMENT_COUNT;  - убрал еще в прошлый раз. Просто не стал редактить в посте, а то получится так что Вы отвечаете не по существу.

Comment: @org - с array_diff действительно все логично, я просто еще не проснулся толком :D

Но вот с т.з. как памяти так и производительности - решение, мягко говоря, не лучшее...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, вот это должно помочь:

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3,6,1,0,4,5,8,15,149); // здесь две единицы.
$arr2 = array_unique($arr1);
$arr3 = array_diff_assoc($arr1,$arr2);
print_r($arr3); // выводит "[4]->1"
```

Только использовать надо `"array_diff_assoc()"`

Answer (score 3):

[[@org](/users/2294/org)](/users/2294/org), алгоритм у вас правильный, но код просто ужасен. Зачем вы лепите `&` где ни попадя? И что за страшный цикл такой? Мой вариант:

```
function search_deplicate($array) {
    $hash = array();
    foreach ($array as $val) {
        if (isset($hash[$val])) {
            return $val;
        }
        $hash[$val] = true;
    }
    return null; 
}
```

[Тесты выдали следующие результаты](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AM3ZaG):

```
       org: 0.011948854923248 sec
      Asen: 0.04189505815506 sec
  drdaeman: 0.0067547178268433 sec
      Ilya: 0.0036947202682495 sec
```

Comment: Да, хороший метод, лучший, пожалуй, если память не поджимает. Жалко в PHP нет нормальных множеств, с ними было бы еще красивее. Господа, плюсуйте этот ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Если жалко памяти на частичную вторую копию (в худшем случае — вторую копию без одного элемента) — отсортировать (`O(n log n)`, скорее всего) и линейно пробежаться по массиву (`O(n)`, надеюсь), ища два одинаковых, идущих подряд, элемента.

Это дешевле варианта с `array_unique`/`array_diff_*` и по времени и по памяти. [Тесты это гарантируют](http://ideone.com/t1XRo) (но не доверяйте, а проверяйте сами).

Если памяти не жалко — см. ответ @[Ilya Pirogov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/105770#107487), он самый быстрый. Пробегам по массиву, сохраняем все увиденное в хэшмап (poor man's set), если уже видели элемент — значит мы его нашли.

Comment: Что-то я на одном тесте ошибся аж 2 раза... 

это действительно намного быстрее любого варианта с diff. 

@drdaeman - уж простите что заставил Вас писать так много тестов, я, на самом деле, не со зла, просто, видимо не стоит проводить каких-либо тестов в воскресенье :D

Comment: Все в порядке, не за что извиняться. Это Вы меня извините, что набросился и вынудил сидеть-перепроверять. Я это тоже не со зла, а исключительно ради истины :)

Comment: А если нам трогать исходный массив нельзя? То память в два раза помножится. Кстати, мои тесты показали что мой метод обгоняет array_diff_assoc

Comment: @org - а если нам трогать исходный массив нельзя тогда это уже другая задача ;D

Answer (score 1):

Можно наверно как-то через  array_unique() и array_diff решить вопрос.

Comment: ума не приложу - как они помогают решить задачу?..

Comment: Да, этот вариант тоже пробовал,но по времени он проигрывает моему. А использовать можно так: array_diff($array,array_unique($array)); - выдаст массив всех повторяющихся элементов.

Comment: А мы разве не массивов ему скармиливаем в количестве двух штук?

Comment: Действительно, прошу прощения, время раннее :D

Comment: Это, пожалуй наилучший способ решения задачи. Плюсую)

Comment: Но array_unique просто удаляет элемент и массив получается с дыркой, поэтому array_diff не находит расхождений. Это лишь мое замечание по тестам, проведенным только что. 
На код
print_r($array);
print_r(array_unique($array));
print_r(array_diff(array_unique($array),$array));
выдает 
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 10
    [6] => 8
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 6
    [9] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 10
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 6
    [9] => 3
)
Array
(
)

Comment: Asen, помоги алгоритму заработать)))

Comment: ओं मणिपद्मे हूं

Comment: @org, помог )))

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(...);
$keys = array_flip(array_flip($array));
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
if (!isset($keys[$i]))
{
echo $array[$i];
break;
}
```

Интересно на сколько это будет долго.

Comment: Долго будет, долго :D

    $i < count($array)